# Solidworks 2024 inverse fillet

Tags: solidworks

How do you inverse the fillet in solidworks 2024 ? Instead of rounding make the "cut" to inside

Expected result:
[image: expected result]

Current result:
[image: current result 1]
[image: current result 2]

Comment: You can try to sweep a cut

Comment: A bit of a philosophical thinking. If you intend something other than blending two surfaces together you should not use fillet. Thisway you underline to the person comming after you that the shape has a function. Similarily dont use hole tool when its not a hole even though its a convenience etc etc. Yes it works but this allows others to decipher your intent better.

Comment: ...or a *Revolved Cut*, if the flange is circular.  Solidworks fillet feature doesn't allow to inverse curvature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Abel](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/29315/abel) for answer

Use **Swept Cut**

[image: 1]
[image: 2]